# A 1950/60s story about time-traveling robots - please help identify

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, robots

OK, I'm going to combine my hate of time-traveling robot questions with my distaste for story identification questions, and try to leverage all'y'all's wisdom to help me remember a story about time traveling robot.

Details I recall:

- Short story.
- A story involved a **time-traveling robot** (duh)
- It was pretty old (before 1970)
- The robot was somewhat confused by the time travels, and mistook the protagonist for an Ivan the Terrible (the Russian Tzar).
- The robot somehow helped turn the protagonist into assorted historical figures (said Ivan the Terrible and if I recall correctly, a Neanderthal?)
- I vaguely recall that the robot could drink some intoxicating (to him) electrical "drink".

Comment: Just to be sure; Is this question serious?

Comment: The plot feels [Scheckleyan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Sheckley), but I don't recall this particular story.

Comment: @bitmask - "[We at the FBI do not have a sense of humor we're aware of](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119654/quotes?qt=qt0402557)"

Comment: @Gilles - I know what you mean but I have a feeling I'd have remembered if it was Sheckley. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: Sounds like an early prototype for [Bender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bender_(Futurama)).

Comment: Why the DV? :))

Comment: If not Sheckley, how about Stanislaw Lem?

Comment: @Fruitbat - wasn't Lem, but your comment gave me a lightbulb on how to tweak my Googling so I found the answer myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, after much Googling, I figured it out myself.

The short story was *[The Ego Machine](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1452864543)* by Henry Kuttner.

Published in *Space Science Fiction May 1952*

> When a slightly mad robot drunk on AC, wants you to join an experiment in optimum ecology—don't do it! After all, who wants to argue like Disraeli or live like Ivan the Terrible?

It's currently [available](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/32108/32108-h/32108-h.htm) on Project Gutenberg